# what is the use of $path in following code

Tags: php

Previously I asked the question about the login page codin where my code was directed to a blank page.I think I found the solution but dont know what the following script do in action field "".Is their any alternative solution to it, so that I don't have to use it.

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="<?php echo $path; ?>system/process-login.php">
 <table>
 <tr align="right">
  <td><span>Username:</span></td>
  <td><input name="uname" id="uname" class="textbox" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">        
  <td><span>Password:</span></td>         
  <td><input name="pass" id="pass" class="textbox" type="password"></td>  
 </tr>   
 <tr>        
  <td></td>        
  <td><input name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="loginbtn" value="Log In" type="submit"></td>          
 </tr>
 <tr>        
  <td></td>        
  <td>Powered by <a href="http://www.creativeben.co.uk/downloads.php">PHP Login Free</a></td>          
 </tr>
 </table>       
</form>
```

Comment: It's just a variable containing a path ?

Comment: The `action=` will determine the target page that PHP will post too. `$path` will be a variable containing the base path.

Comment: But where is $path actually declared.I have seen all the scripts,but can't find.

Answer (score 1):

When form will submit action will be go to `"$path"/system/process-login.php`

`$path` contain base path

e.g

```
http://localhost/system/process-login.php
```

Comment: Ok...can we go without using it?

Comment: May be or not. its depend on value of $path. if $path values is e.g 'http://localhost/' then you can go without it.